# How to play mp3-file in Angular4 correctly?

Tags: angular, mp3

I have ASP.NET WebAPI-based RESTful service, from which I retrieve information about my **mp3** track in the following format:

```
{
  data: '/+NIxAAAAAAAAAA...'
  name: 'My song',
  artist: 'My artist'
}
```

How should I write a component with Angular 4, which allows me to play this track in browser, using HTML 5 audio tag, or something else?